# Trying to run a function from a dynamically loaded javascript script

Tags: javascript

Hi I need some help here I'm trying to figure out why DOM can't find the functions loaded dynamically from other javascripts files. Some points about what is going on where would be great.

CHROME ERROR: Uncaught ReferenceError: start_canvas is not defined

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script src="assets/scripts/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //previous erroneous code load_script("assets/scripts/script.js", ()=>{});
    load_script("assets/scripts/start_canvas.js", ()=>{});
    window.onload = () => start_canvas();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**JS - main.js**

```
function load_script(url, callback) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = url;
    if (callback != null) {
        script.onload = function () {
            callback();
        };
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

**JS - start_canvas.js**

```
function start_canvas() {
    alert("bar");
}
```

thanks !

Comment: Where is 'start_canvas.js' being loaded? None of the code you have shown accomplishes that.

Comment: @terrymorse you are right changing it

Comment: *slaps my own face*
THANK YOU BOWS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your script file name to **start_canvas.js**. it is assets/scripts/**script.js** in your code

```
 load_script("assets/scripts/start_canvas.js", ()=>{});
```

Comment: yes it is sorry I didn't simplified that but I'm working in a larger project the path is correct

Comment: your codes work well if references/paths are well

Comment: thank you yeah I did edit the question it was a path error !

Answer (score 2):

In your code call the callback in the right place

```js
 load_script("assets/scripts/script.js", () => start_canvas());
```